# How to compare table values with Jquery

Tags: jquery, django-templates

I'm working on creating a golf app. What i'm trying to do is highlight the holes where the index of the hole is greater than the players handicap. I'm struggling with how I could do this with jquery. Any idea why my jquery isn't working? (note: i'm only testing on one player right now)

Here is what  I currently have:

```js
$(function() {
  $("tee-index").each(function() {
    if ($(this).value() > '#index-player-1') {
      $(this).css('color', 'red');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id='table1' style="table-layout:fixed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <tbody>
        {% for players in teetime_data.Players.all %}
        <tr>
          <th class="th-score" scope="col">{{players.golfer.first_name}}</th>
          <th class="th-score" id="index-player-{{forloop.counter}}" scope="col">{{players.hcp_index}}</th>
          <td class="td-score" scope="col">{{score_form.hole_1_score}}</td>
          <td class="td-score">{{score_form.hole_2_score}}</td>
          <td class="td-score">{{score_form.hole_3_score}}</td>
          <td class="td-score">{{score_form.hole_4_score}}</td>
          <td class="td-score">{{score_form.hole_5_score}}</td>
          <td class="td-score">{{score_form.hole_6_score}}</td>
          <td class="td-score">{{score_form.hole_7_score}}</td>
          <td class="td-score">{{score_form.hole_8_score}}</td>
          <td class="td-score">{{score_form.hole_9_score}}</td>
          <td class="td-score">{{score_form.hole_10_score}}</td>
          <td class="td-score">{{score_form.hole_11_score}}</td>
          <td class="td-score">{{score_form.hole_12_score}}</td>
          <td class="td-score">{{score_form.hole_13_score}}</td>
          <td class="td-score">{{score_form.hole_14_score}}</td>
          <td class="td-score">{{score_form.hole_15_score}}</td>
          <td class="td-score">{{score_form.hole_16_score}}</td>
          <td class="td-score">{{score_form.hole_17_score}}</td>
          <td class="td-score">{{score_form.hole_18_score}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th class="th-score" scope="col">Index</th>
            <th class="th-score" scope="col"></th>
            <th class="th-score tee-index" scope="col">{{teetime_data.tee.hole_1_index}}</th>
            <th class="th-score tee-index" scope="col">{{teetime_data.tee.hole_2_index}}</th>
            <th class="th-score tee-index" scope="col">{{teetime_data.tee.hole_3_index}}</th>
            <th class="th-score tee-index" scope="col">{{teetime_data.tee.hole_4_index}}</th>
            <th class="th-score tee-index" scope="col">{{teetime_data.tee.hole_5_index}}</th>
            <th class="th-score tee-index" scope="col">{{teetime_data.tee.hole_6_index}}</th>
            <th class="th-score tee-index" scope="col">{{teetime_data.tee.hole_7_index}}</th>
            <th class="th-score tee-index" scope="col">{{teetime_data.tee.hole_8_index}}</th>
            <th class="th-score tee-index" scope="col">{{teetime_data.tee.hole_9_index}}</th>
            <th class="th-score tee-index" scope="col">{{teetime_data.tee.hole_10_index}}</th>
            <th class="th-score tee-index" scope="col">{{teetime_data.tee.hole_11_index}}</th>
            <th class="th-score tee-index" scope="col">{{teetime_data.tee.hole_12_index}}</th>
            <th class="th-score tee-index" scope="col">{{teetime_data.tee.hole_13_index}}</th>
            <th class="th-score tee-index" scope="col">{{teetime_data.tee.hole_14_index}}</th>
            <th class="th-score tee-index" scope="col">{{teetime_data.tee.hole_15_index}}</th>
            <th class="th-score tee-index" scope="col">{{teetime_data.tee.hole_16_index}}</th>
            <th class="th-score tee-index" scope="col">{{teetime_data.tee.hole_17_index}}</th>
            <th class="th-score tee-index" scope="col">{{teetime_data.tee.hole_18_index}}</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: This is not related to DJANGO at all. Please [edit] the snippet I made you and replace the templating with RENDERED HTML to make a [mcve]

Comment: When developing in javascript **always** have the console window open (or other method to get console errors ofc) - and look for errors that the browser is kind enough to provide for you.  In this case `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).value is not a function` - even if you had used `.val()`, table cells `td` do not have a `value` - use `$(this).text()`

Comment: Also this is not valid HTML `<thead>
    <tr>
      <tbody>`

Comment: `[value] > '#index-player-1'` will compare the value with the *string literal* `"#index-player1"` - you probably wanted `$("#index-player-1").text() * 1` here, but it's impossible to tell as you've not included that element in your code.  **Edit** nvm, found it as `id="index-player-{{forloop.counter}}"` - if `forloop.counter` is 0-based, then you'll have a #index-player-0 not -1.   As noted above, please include the *rendered* HTML for jquery/javascript questions.

Comment: I am using bootstrap, and based on their tables, <thead> <tr> and <tbody> are valid

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/tables/

Comment: Nowhere on that bootstrap page does the construct `thead > tr > tbody` appear.  You *should* always add the closing `</tr>` and `</thead>` before `<tbody>` even though it's not technically mandatory according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead#technical_summary

Answer (score 0):

1. cells have .text(), form fields have .val()
2. `<thead>     <tr>       <tbody>` is invalid HTML
3. `if ($(this).value() > '#index-player-1') {` is wishful thinking/pseudo code

I assume, once you have proper HTML, we can tweak this

I assume you wanted to color the player's cell and not the index footer's cell red. I use a class `.red { color: red }` instead of css since it can be toggled on and off

```
$(function() {
  $("#table1 tbody tr").each(function() { // players
    const $scoreCells = $(".td-score",this); // score cells of that player
    $scoreCells.each(function(i, el) {
      const indexValue = +$(".tee-index").eq(i).text(); 
      $(this).toggleClass('red',indexValue > +$(el).text())
    });
  });
});
```